# CloudML RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Everything seems to work fine when I test locally. When I submit the job remotely:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
  --job-dir gs://$BUCKET_NAME/$JOB_NAME \
  --runtime-version 1.7 \
```

I get the following errors:
[image]
[image]

In my code, the only place I use numpy is to load my file - `data.npz` using:

```
train_file = gs://path_to_data.npz
f = BytesIO(file_io.read_file_to_string(train_file, binary_mode=True))
data = np.load(f)
```

To create the .npz, I used `google-datalab` which has numpy v 1.14, while 1.7 runtime for CloudML has 1.13.3, but I doubt this is the reason. My local machine also has 1.13.3 and doesn't seem to display errors.

*The job still gets completed successfully, I would just like to get rid of these warnings/errors.*

Answer (score 0):

We're aware of these warning messages and are working on addressing them in Runtime Version 1.8, which we hope to release soon.